# How can I shrink the parent div to the size of its child?

Tags: html, css

I have boxes with different dimensions - some fixed and some dynamic. I need a wrapper-div that applies a border without changing the HTML code or the child's CSS (only change `.one`'s CSS)

How can I do this so both boxes in the below snippet keep their respective size but the parent is not larger than them?

```css
.one {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

#two {
  height: 60px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

#three {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="one">
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: would `.one { display: inline-block; }` be good for you ?

Comment: or why not just add the max width to the parent?

Comment: @Pete because I can't fix the parents width. The child is slotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only about a visual style use a filter like below. The more filter you add the more you get close to a solid edge

```css
.one {
  filter:
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue)
    drop-shadow(0 0 0.5px blue);
}

#two {
  height: 60px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

#three {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="one">
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to 'shrink' `.two`.

My approach would be using a static `width`, with an `inline-block` on `.one`:

```css
.one {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  height: 60px;
      width: 320px;
  max-width: 320px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another option, using `display: inline-flex;` on the `.one`, with an static with on `.two`:

```css
.one {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.two {
  height: 60px;
      width: 320px;
  max-width: 320px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

---

Using [`flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), you can let `.two` 'grow' to the size of `.one`, the only downside to this, is that you'll need the `320px` on `.one`, but in the end, using flex offer more options

```css
.one {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  height: 60px;
  width: 320px;
}

.two {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

---

As [@Tacoshy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358198/how-can-i-shrink-the-parent-div-to-the-size-of-its-child/65358357?noredirect=1#comment115548349_65358357) mentioned in the comments, another way is using `width: min-content` on the `.one`. Should be noted that IE [doesn't yet support that property.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_min-content)

```css
.one {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  width: min-content;
}

.two {
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 320px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: just to complete your perfectly fine anwser: you could also use `width: min-content;` for the parent. It will size the parent to the size of the widest children.

Comment: I just discovered none of these work for me. I changed my question to describe my problem in a more detailed way. Also pinging @tacoshy.

Comment: how do you want to shrink the parent to 320px while still maintining to span the entire width? it either shrink or maintain width. But not possible to do both. Otherwise you would need to shrink the entire website down to 320px

Comment: @tacoshy See Temani Afif's answer. It seems to be possible after all (:

Comment: Yes but he not shrinks the parent he shrinks the child or limits the parent to 320px which was said at the other answers swell.

Comment: @tacoshy If you look at my edited snippet, none of the answers listed here work while his answer does. I'm sorry if I worded my question confusingly.

Comment: "*There are many ways to 'shrink' `.two`.*" Isn't it `.one` that OP wants to shrink? The parent/wrapper?